# How can I delete files not seen from the web?

Tags: html, web-applications

A few days ago I started working on a huge site, that was developed before me as a static site.

It was made using dreamweaver and its template system, but in the end it's all static html+css.

I want to clean the site before strating to use a CVS, so I was plannig to delete the files that can't be accessed from links from outside. That includes html not linked, css files not used, images not used, javascript, and pdfs, maybe there are some .exe or .ppt/.pps.

Is there any way to check which files are NOT being used?
(i.e. not linked)

EDIT: This site is big, about 10Gib in around 10.000 files. Apparently a third of that, is not being used. So the solution would be an automatic or semi automatic tool.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there is a better way but I once used the IIS SEO (search engine optimization) utility and removed the files that didn't appear in the report.  It also provides other useful information if you need it.

[SEO Toolkit](http://www.iis.net/download/seotoolkit)

Comment: Do I need to host my site in an IIS with SEO toolkit? Or can I use it from another computer?

Comment: I believe the only thing you need to host in IIS is the SEO toolkit.  When you start your tests if will ask you for a URL to start and in the advanced options you can provide credentials. I have always ran the utility locally though.

Comment: Also, after your test is finished at the top of the dashboard to the right of '<- Back To Reports' there is a 'Report' drop down that will allow you to download all the URLs.  This will include every linked file it encountered along with its status and recommendations (pages, images, javascript, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Get a good HTML editor  that has find/replace function that can search all files in a specified directory. Notepad++ fits those requirements nicely.

Then run the Find-In-Files (in NOtepad++, that's ctr+shift+f) command for the filename. Careful, sometimes hrefs specify no directory (say, it's linked from a sibling page), sometimes the specify part or all of the path from the root directory. So search by filename only. If no result, then no links. If there's a result, but other files in other directories have the same filename, you need to inspect carefully.

Comment: That is ok, but for small sites. I should say, this site is abot 10Gib in around 10.000 files. Apparently a third of that, is not being used.